# javafx pane not being created

Tags: java, class, javafx, pane

My JavaFx code does not work as it should do. I am trying to create 10X10 text matrix populated with either a 1 or 0, so it looks similar to a 2d array filled with 1's and 0's. When I put the code that is currently in the MatrixPane class in main it works fine, but with this code it just sets the scene but it looks like no pane is added or created.

If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

I realize I have Imported some unused things, I am using them for other parts of the program.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Button1 extends Application
{
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        MatrixPane Matrix = new MatrixPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(Matrix);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("1 window "); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}


class MatrixPane extends Pane
{
    double HEIGHT = 500;
    double WIDTH = 200;
    private GridPane pane1 = new GridPane();

    public MatrixPane()
    {
    }

    public void fillmatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                TextField text = new TextField(Integer.toString((int)(Math.random() * 2)));
                text.setMinWidth(WIDTH / 8.0);
                text.setMaxWidth(WIDTH / 10.0);
                text.setMinHeight(HEIGHT / 8.0);
                text.setMaxHeight(HEIGHT / 10.0);
                this.pane1.add(text, j, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I checked your code and you are excessively using `GridPane`. First you have a class named `MatrixPane` which inherits `Pane`, but also this class has a property `GridPane`. Finally, you use `GridPane` once again to add `MatrixPane`!

So, what I did is to use composition, but first I change the `start` method

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

  GridPane pane = new GridPane();
  MatrixPane Matrix = new MatrixPane();
  //pane.getChildren().add(Matrix);
  Matrix.fillmatrix();
  Scene scene = new Scene(Matrix.getPane1(), 700, 500);
  ...
```

So here the scene is going to receive the data of `pane1`, this attribute has the values stored when `fillmatrix` was called.

Then I add the getter method in `MatrixPane` for the attribute `pane1`

```
class MatrixPane {

  double HEIGHT = 500;
  double WIDTH = 200;
  private GridPane pane1 = new GridPane();

  public GridPane getPane1() {
    return pane1;
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you again! It worked Great! Really Appreciate it!

Comment: No need to make `MatrixPane` extend `Pane` if you don't use any of the methods inherited from `Pane` or the fact that it's a instance of `Pane`. Either the `MatrixPane` should extend `GridPane` itself and not contain a field or at the `GridPane` should be added to the children of the instance that contains it, if e.g. brackets should be added to the matrix... Or if it should be a kind of "layout manager" it should extend `Object` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Call `fillMatrix();` method from `Button1.start()`

Add GridPane to MatrixPane in MatrixPane construcor

```
private GridPane pane1 = new GridPane();

public MatrixPane() {
    getChildren().add(pane1);
}
```

This will work.